# Paste multiple values into output of renderText

Tags: r

I have a shiny code like this

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("censusVis"),
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        helpText("Create demographic maps with
           information from the 2010 US Census."),
       
        selectInput("var",
                    label = "Choose a variable to display",
                    choices = c("Percent White",
                                "Percent Black",
                                "Percent Hispanic",
                                "Percent Asian"),
                    selected = "Percent White",multiple = T),
       
        sliderInput("range",
                    label = "Range of interest:",
                    min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
    ),
     mainPanel(textOutput("selected_var"))))

 server <- function(input, output) {

output$selected_var <- renderText({
    paste("You have selected", input$var)})}
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I am choosing multiple selection it is coming as "You have selected xxxx You have selected yyyy ".

How to paste these output as like this:

```
You have selected xxxx yyyyy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
paste(c("You have selected", input$var), collapse = " ")
```